# How to redirect in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC 3 using C# I want to redirect certain methods that are not verified. However, this doesn't seem like it's working:

```
    private ActionResult m_VerifyLogin()
    {
        if (Session["isLogged"] == null || (int)Session["isLogged"] != 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Does anyone know what I can do? Even if I create an ActionFilterAttribute I would like it to be very simple!

-- EDIT --

Thanks for all your answers guys. We tried some of what you asked and then we came up with this after testing:

**A custom ActionFilterAttribute:**

```
public class IsLoggedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["isLogged"] == null || (int) filterContext.HttpContext.Session["isLogged"] != 1)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home" });
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

}
```

And I can throw [IsLogged] above a routed method.

Comment: It's "not working"?  Do tell!

Comment: Why isn't it working? What happens?

Comment: have you tried debugging to see if it his your `return RedirectToAction` line of code..?

Comment: It should work as is. What is contained within Session["isLogged"] anyways?

Comment: Do I need to restart my server to flush a session? I had it working with the same code before I made this method. The way Im calling it is: m_VerifyLogin();  -- Do I need to do return m_VerifyLogin(); ?

Comment: @JREAM: Don't restart your server (as in machine), just either restart IIS or re-save web.config file, that will stop the app.

Answer (score 5):

Make your action method `public`. Your code looks nice because to redirect to another action/controller the action method could return by `RedirectToAction` method from Controller base class.

```
public ActionResult m_VerifyLogin()
{
    if (Session["isLogged"] != null || (int)Session["isLogged"] != 1)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Your `if` statement is a little bit strange too. You check if the value in session is null and with a `OR` logic operator you also cast it (that could be null) to test with a value. You could try to do something like this:

```
//If session value is not null then try to cast to int and check if it is not 1.
if (Session["isLogged"] != null || (int)Session["isLogged"] != 1)
```

If the `Index` action in `Home` controller has an `ActionFilterAttribute` applied and it is invalid by the current user, you will get a redirect to login page defined on the forms authentication configuration. You also can use action method name with a better name to get a friendly url, something like `VerifyLogin`.

```
public ActionResult VerifyLogin()
{
    if (Session["isLogged"] != null || (int)Session["isLogged"] != 1)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: But Im not using this as a URL call, its so I can just pop a function inside my ActionResults such as Index, Dashboard I just call m_VerifyLogin();

Comment: `m_Something` is already non C# convention. +1 for the whole answer.

Comment: I added some tips in my awnser. If you have a private method, you will not get a valid route to this action method, because it is private. Such as class in .Net Framework, Controllers is classes and it has access modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

`RedirectToAction()` returns a `RedirectToRouteResult` object that tells MVC to send a redirect when you return it **from your action**.

Calling the method without using its return value won't do anything.

You need to return the result of your private method from the action itself.